# Can a modal form in Delphi be non-blocking?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

I'm looking to create a modal form in Delphi that prevents the user interface from being interacted with, but still allows execution of the other forms to continue. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just move the things you want to have happen OUT of the forms and into somewhere else where they belong?  Some people go as far as MVC, I just go as far as not putting all my logic in my forms.

Comment: This question is not clear for me. I mean, what do you really want? User Interaction or execution of code?

Comment: I thought the whole design purpose of Modal forms was to prevent the background from being interacted with unless I am misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 3):

A modal form is invoked by calling a function, `ShowModal`, that only returns when the modal form closes. If you want to execute code on the same thread, the UI thread, then it would need to be invoked from inside `ShowModal`. In almost all cases that's not a tenable approach. From which we can conclude that the code in question must be executed in a thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Windows continues to process messages in the background, so any updates that happen on a timer, for instance, will still occur. It's just that all keyboard and mouse events are directed to the modal form. In theory you could post messages to another form to "action" some code if you want. There are lots of things you can do still in the main thread - the question is whether this is what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 2):

A form in itself has no 'execution', but you can use threads to execute code in the background while there is a (modal) form active.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, although not recommended.

I've done this to show a progress form to say the application is busy while still continuing on the main thread.

The idea is to take the code inside ShowModal and split it in half, removing the repeat until loop as you do so.

You can call the first half to show the form and you must guarentee to call the second half to close it again.

Something along the lines of

```
NonBlockingModalForm =  TNonBlockingModalForm.Create();
try
    NonBlockingModalForm.FirstHalfOfShowModal;
    DoStuff;
finally
    NonBlockingModalForm.SecondHalfOfShowModal;
    NonBlockingModalForm.Free;
end;
```

Note that in the loop within ShowModal there is a call to Application.HandleMessage abd checks for the app being terminated.

You'll need to do these if you want your UI to play nicely.